# What attenuator to use for using HackRF one to simulate GPS for in production testing?

Tags: rf, gps, test-equipment, production

I am trying to use the HackRF One to simulate GPS to test devices in a production environment. I am currently able to get the GPS signal on my GPS receiver that I am testing, but the signal is much stronger than the devices would see in the real world. I want the GPS signal to be more representative of the outside environment to ensure that the devices I am manufacturing actually work in the field, so i am trying to decrease the GPS signal.

I know that GPS signal outside is low This document says that ["the received power is -125 dBm"](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75016740.pdf). The [HackRF One User document](https://hackrf.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) says that the maximum output power for 1575.42 MHz is between 0 dbm to 10dbm. [image] The antenna I have attached to the HackRF One has a gain of -3.34 db. So if I assume that the HackRF One is 2.5 dbm at 1575.42 MHz then I need a ~-125 db attenuator. -125dbm + 2.5dbm -3.34 db =attenuator = ~125 db. Is this math correct to assume that I need a -125 db attenuator? Am I missing something?

P.S. I am using the HackRF One in a RF chamber to do this testing to not interfere with other devices.

edit: changed "reprehensive" to representative

Comment: "[reprehensive](https://www.google.com/search?q=reprehensive&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" - I do not think it means what you think it means ... "representative" perhaps?

Comment: I meant "representative" I will correct it.

Comment: On page 17 of the data sheet to which you provided the link, is says that you can control the Tx power with a stepped 14 dB gain control (or attenuation) and a 0 dB to 47 dB variable gain (or attenuation).  So by taking advantage of those, you should be able to reduce the transmit output power by 61 dB from it's maximum.  Hence you would only need ~65 dB additional attenuation to achieve the power level you want.

Comment: *Enclosure: The commercial version of HackRF One from Great Scott Gadgets ships with an injection molded plastic enclosure.* RF radiation from the PCB itself will  **very** likely exceed radiation from an antenna connected through 125 dB attenuator attached to RF output.

Comment: @glen_geek You are probably right. I might but the HackRF in another RF chamber to ensure that the HackRF is not radiating unwanted signal.

Comment: mgwalker95 - shielding is easier said than done, *especially* when power and USB signals are required for HackRF operation. A USB cable will radiate substantial RF .

Comment: @glen_geek RF shielding is not that hard to do. Use a battery to power a raspberry pi, use the raspberry pi to power and run the HackRF put that into a RFchamber, then run a coax cable from the HackRF through the sma on the RF chamber to the other RF chamber with the GPS antenna inside. This should get rid of most of the signal getting out or getting in.